# Simple TAI (TrustAssociationInterceptor) with Websphere AS

Tags: websphere, jaas

Trying make simple implementation of TAI.
Created TAI class which for each user set login "user1" and "user-group" list without using UserRegistry.
Added role-group mapping into my ear-file ("user-group"=>"user-role").
Added security constraint for my war: allow access resources for users with role "user role". After trying access page have 403 error:

```
[11.05.15 19:43:27:444 MSK] 0000007c WebCollaborat A   SECJ0129E: ... user2:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm ... default_host:/war/page.html, Authorization failed, Not granted any of the required roles: user-role
```

What was I wrong?
Using WAS 8.5.5.

My TAI implementation:

```
package ru.test.tai;

// imports

public class SimpleTAI implements TrustAssociationInterceptor {
    public SimpleTAI() {
        super();
    }

    public boolean isTargetInterceptor(HttpServletRequest req)
            throws WebTrustAssociationException {
        System.out.println("isTargetInterceptor called");
        if (req.getRequestURI().matches(".*war.*")) {
            System.out.println("true");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public TAIResult negotiateValidateandEstablishTrust(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse resp) throws WebTrustAssociationFailedException {

        String userid = "user2";
        String uniqueid = "user2";
        List<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();
        groups.add("user-group");
        String key = "user1Key";
        Subject subject = createSubject(userid, uniqueid, groups, key);
        return TAIResult.create(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, "notused", subject);
    }

    public int initialize(Properties arg0)
            throws WebTrustAssociationFailedException {
        return 0;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return "1.0";
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }

    public void cleanup() {
    }

    private Subject createSubject(String userid, String uniqueid, List groups,
            String key) {
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
        hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_UNIQUEID, uniqueid);
        hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_SECURITYNAME, userid);
        hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_GROUPS, groups);
        System.out.println("Subject cache key is " + key);
        hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_CACHE_KEY, key);
        subject.getPublicCredentials().add(hashtable);

        return subject;
    }
}
```

ibm-application-bnd.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <security-role name="user-role">
        <group name="user-group" />
    </security-role>
</application-bnd>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using groups non existing in the registry, then in the `ibm-application-bnd.xml` you have to add `access-id` like this (sample shows user, group):

```
<security-role name="user-role">
   <user name="test" access-id="user:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/test"/>
   <group name="user-group" access-id="group:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/user-group"/>
</security-role>
```

Realm should match your currently configured user registry.

Comment: Should I add custom realm containing groups and users to implement security? Is this best-practice for custom authentification?
Also how I must to say for TAI: "this user is from this custom realm"?

Comment: @Gregory - depends really on your requirements. The best practice is to use some well known user registry, like LDAP, as user assignment can be easily manageable externally by application/system admins. If you need custom user store, it might be better to implement [user registry](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwim_userregbridge.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-8-2-33-2-1-3-25-0&lang=en) instead of TAI. TAI is mostly for customizing authentication to the existing registry.

Comment: @Gregory You can map certain registry to the server via Security Domains. In general it is broad subject and you have many options, so solution really depends on your requirements.